# Interrupted Ubuntu installation and deleted(?) GRUB

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi, grubrescue

I have made an attempt to install Ubuntu 18.10, overwriting existing Ubuntu 15.10. There is also Windows 7 on this PC. The installation taken very long (around 6h) and did not complete. During it the power supply was gone and next run of the computer welcomed me with black screen:

```
error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc-normal.mod' not found
Entering rescue mode
```

I typed

```
ls
```

and following was displayed:

```
(hd0), (hd0,msdos7), (hd0,msdos6), (hd0,msdos5), (hd0,msdos2), (hd0,msdos1)
```

Than I typed "ls (hd0)" and similar for all displayed. In case of msdos6 it replied:

```
Filesystem is ext2.
```

In all other cases it was:

```
Filesystem is unknown.
```

Comment: Please launch `gparted` (install if not installed) and post a screen shot of the partitions seen by gparted!

Answer (score 0):

See here first tbefore attempting: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReinstallWindowsWithoutLosingUbuntu

The graphical way

1. Turn off machine and insert installation usb, boot your machine and select `try ubuntu`.
2. Install and run Boot-Repair
3. Click "Recommended Repair".
   Now reboot your system. The usual GRUB boot menu should appear. If it does not, hold Left Shift while booting. You will be able to choose between Ubuntu and Windows.

Source:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had to skip Reinstalling Windows before restoring GRUB - as I do not have Windows CD by me now.

Ubuntu runs with no problem now and when I press left shift, GNU GRUB screen appears indeed. However there are only 3 options:
Ubuntu
Advanced options for Ubuntu
System setup

System setup leads to 
    error: can't find command 'fwsetup'.
    Press any key to continue
There is nothing that would allow me to run WIndows. However from level of Ubuntu I can find my Windows files undamages - just can not acces to the Windows system itself.

Comment: PS: I can acces even a directory /Windows/Boot - maybe there is something I could use to restore it from Ubuntu level?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it: I have indeed restored GRUB with boot-repair from level of CD with Ubuntu. After that, when accessed to already installed Ubuntu normally I have installed boot-repair again. There is an option, in advanced ones, to change "OS to boot by default" from "OS now in use - Ubuntu" to "Windows (selected via menu)". Now it works perfect.

PS: I have reinstalled Ubuntu 18.10 for experiment and issues as above occured again. Same procedure helped again. Maybe that is because Ubuntu 18.10 installs GRUB2 during OS installation?